# Adding font-size to HTML overrides all my font-sizes

Tags: html, css, font-size

I font weird behavior if  I added font-size to html

```
 html {
            font-size: 10px;
        }
```

it will override all font-sizes I have  on all html tags  and it will make them smaller

I want to keep the font-size on html but  I have one div  that I won't it to be effected by html font size

Here an example

https://jsfiddle.net/Ldgworje/1/

try to remove the html from CSS and try

I want to keep the font-size for html but  I have one div  that I don't want it to be effected by html font size

as you see in the example

I hope you can help

Comment: There's a reason why they call it **Cascading** Style Sheet. In any case, when you ask questions on SO, you are **required** to post a [mcve] **within your question** and not a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because you are using rem for the font size. rem and em are supposed to work that way. Check https://kyleschaeffer.com/development/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs/

If you do not want rating to be affected use px instead.

Answer (score 1):

What you do is you add a rule **after** that html font rule, and you create an ID for that div and you set font size to whatever:

```
html {
    font-size: 10px;
}

div#fontSize {
    font-size: 14px; /*Or whatever size you want*/
}
```

If you want to leave the font size the same as the default for the div element, then just set it to `1em`, as below:

```
div#fontSize {
    font-size: 1em; /*Sets this size to 16px, which is default*/
}
```

Simple! Just ask if you need any help/explanations/fiddles.

Comment: Note that `em` sizing is relative to the element's direct or nearest parent. If OP were to set the `div` to `font-size: 1em`, it would result in 10px because of the `font-size` OP set for `html` which is inherited by the other elements in the example.